# Puppet won't start MySQL

Tags: mysql, vagrant, puppet, ubuntu-14.04

I'm making my live easier (I hope) by learning to use puppet and vagrant.
I already know how to work with Vagrant but want to make a configuration that out of the box has everything set-up to start. So I thought to use Puppet.
I used the tutorial at http://jamesmcfadden.co.uk/using-vagrant-and-puppet-to-build-a-php-nginx-and-mysql-environment/ but can't seem to figure out how to start MySQL.

Running Ubuntu 14.04LTS my init.pp for MySQL is

```
    class mysql {

  # Install mysql
  package { ['mysql-server']:
    ensure => present,
    require => Exec['apt-get update'],
  }

  # Run mysql
  service { 'mysql':
    ensure  => running,
    require => Package['mysql-server'],
  }

  # Use a custom mysql configuration file
  file { '/etc/mysql/my.cnf':
    source  => 'puppet:///modules/mysql/my.cnf',
    require => Package['mysql-server'],
    notify  => Service['mysql'],
  }

  # We set the root password here
  exec { 'set-mysql-password':
    unless  => 'mysqladmin -uroot -proot status',
    command => "mysqladmin -uroot password a9120ed2b58af37862a83f5b9f850819ed08b2a9",
    path    => ['/bin', '/usr/bin'],
    require => Service['mysql'];
  }
}
```

But this gives me an error that mysql is not found.

```
err: /Stage[main]/Mysql/Service[mysql]/ensure: change from stopped to running fa
iled: Could not start Service[mysql]: Execution of '/sbin/start mysql' returned
1:  at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-2/modules-0/mysql/manifests/init.pp:13
```

And changing it to mysqld (note the 'd') this message is gone but there are problems coming up with the dependencies that can't be found to check if mysql is running (after changing them to 'Service['mysqld']':

```
err: /Stage[main]/Mysql/Service[mysqld]: Could not evaluate: Could not find init
 script or upstart conf file for 'mysqld'
```

Were am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Apparently `mysql` without the trailing *d* is correct, but you need to investigate the reason for the start script failing. Try *syslog* or any dedicated `mysql` logs that you may have the service write.

Answer (score 0):

your script has the below lines:

> require => Exec['apt-get update'],

but don't define the 'Exec'. Add following lines:

```
exec { 'apt-get update':

command => 'sudo apt-get update',

path    => ['/bin', '/usr/bin'],

}
```

Should work fine afterward.

Answer (score -2):

Do not try to write your own MySQL module. Please use officially supported [puppet MySQ](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql)L module. To install it call:

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-mysql
```

Generally, if you want to install/manage some application by puppet, first check if on [puppet forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/) exist dedicated module.